# How to find the Birthday of FRIENDS Who are celebrating today using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

How to find the Birthday of FRIENDS Who are celebrating today using PHP and MYSQL

thanks in Advance...

Fero

Comment: Where are your friends information, in the database? What do the tables look like, etc?

Comment: People can make guesses but to give a solid answer, I would need to look at the actual data structure

Comment: This question and your answer are not helpful at all. Too ambigous

Comment: I keep my friends birthdays in my google calendar so i can easily rember them. Facebook is a grate tool to!

Answer (score 8):

This one handles February 29 - treating March 1st as the celebration day in non-leap years.

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users u INNER JOIN friendships f ON (f.user_id = u.id)
WHERE f.friend_id = 6 -- whatever your id is
    AND (
        MONTH(u.birthdate) = MONTH(NOW())
        AND DAY(u.birthdate) = DAY(NOW())
    ) OR (
        MONTH(c.birthdate) = 2 AND DAY(c.birthdate) = 29
        AND MONTH(NOW()) = 3 AND DAY(NOW()) = 1
        AND (YEAR(NOW()) % 4 = 0)
        AND ((YEAR(NOW()) % 100 != 0) OR (YEAR(NOW()) % 400 = 0))
    )
```

Having not see your table structure, I just made a guess about how you handle friendship links

Comment: +1 for bothering with the 1:1461 people who were born on a leap day (approx).  They might prefer to celebrate on the last day of February, of course :D  But, like they say, you can't please all of the people all of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate cURL calls to http://www.birthdatabase.com within your application and read in the HTML results.

**Edit** - I may have misunderstood your question. If you're trying to pull birthdays from another database (not your own), this could be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make separate fields for month and day to make selects faster.

Answer (score -3):

Thanks all

I got the answer...

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE MONTH(`birthdate`) = MONTH(NOW()) AND
     DAYOFMONTH(`birthdate`) = DAYOFMONTH(NOW());
```

By using this query we can able to get the Data we want

Fero

Comment: What happened to the friends?