# Mysql Dayofyear in leap year

Tags: mysql, leap-year

In the following query the leap year is not taken into account.

```
 SELECT      e.id,
             e.title,
             e.birthdate
 FROM        employers e
 WHERE       DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) <= DAYOFYEAR(e.birthdate)
 AND         DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) +14 >= DAYOFYEAR(e.birthdate)
```

So in this query the birthdate of someone who is born in a leap year has got a different dayofyear in a non leap year.

How can i adjust the query to make sure it also works in a leap year?

The mysql version i have is: 5.0.67

Comment: ok, thought at first you were trying to claim a bug in the `DAYOFYEAR` function.  So, of course, the `DAYOFYEAR` is different in a leap year.  You need to explain why that's a problem.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with that query?

Comment: Define works. Of course DayOfYear is different in a leap year, there's one more day in it.

Comment: I want to show upcoming birthdays of employers. The point is that in a leap year, the person who has his birthday today is not shown in the website. Because the dayofyear of his birthday has passed already. So how can i make this query leap year proof?

Comment: You need to do DAYOFYEAR(e.birthdate) where birthdate is current year, not year of birth.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: If he does that, he'll get `NULL` for years that don't have a February 29th.

Comment: @Crontab, apparently, `DAYOFYEAR()` for February 29th on non-leap years equals March 1st (60).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Where `NOW()` is a non-leap year `2011`, the problem arises from anybody born on a leap year after February 29 will have an extra day because you are using `DAYOFYEAR` against the birth year.

```
DAYOFYEAR('2004-04-01') // DAYOFYEAR(e.birthdate) Returns 92
DAYOFYEAR('2011-04-01') // DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) Returns 91
```

Where you do `DAYOFYEAR`, you need the birthdate from the current year, not the year of birth.

So, instead of:

```
DAYOFYEAR(e.birthdate)
```

You can convert it to this year like this:

```
DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(e.birthdate, INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(e.birthdate)) YEAR))
```

Which converts a birthdate of:

```
'2004-04-01'
```

To:

```
'2011-04-01'
```

So, here's the modified query:

```
SELECT      e.id,
             e.title,
             e.birthdate
 FROM        employers e
 WHERE       DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) <= DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(e.birthdate, INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(e.birthday)) YEAR))
 AND         DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) +14 >= DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(e.birthdate, INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(e.birthday)) YEAR))
```

People born on February 29th will fall on March 1st on non-leap years, which is still day `60`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 365 days in a normal year, 366 in a leap year.  In a normal year, March 1 would be the 60th day of the year.  In a leap year, February 29 would be the 60th day of the year.  The MySQL function is consistent.

If you **really** wanted to make it more complicated than it has to be, you could add a day to your `DAYOFYEAR(curdate())` if `curdate()` is greater than or equal to March 1 AND `curdate()` isn't in a leap year.  But I wouldn't recommend doing that.

Comment: I didn't say the function is inconsistent. read my comment on my start post!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a related solution

[How to find the Birthday of FRIENDS Who are celebrating today using PHP and MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490488/how-to-find-the-birthday-of-friends-who-are-)
celebrating-today-using-php-and-mysq

If I understand correctly, the problem you are having is that if your birthday is March 1, since you're looking for the (nth) 60th day of the year, you are getting the wrong day sometimes.

I believe the query in the above solution addresses the issue